# Vector of a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm trying to create a vector of a struct. I have some problems with creating the vector with the struct.

Here's the error message:

```
testt.cpp: In constructor 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector<_Tp, _Al
loc>::size_type, const value_type&, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = flowPath;
 _Alloc = std::allocator<flowPath>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsign
ed int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = flowPath; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc
>::allocator_type = std::allocator<flowPath>]':
testt.cpp:20:28: error: no matching function for call to 'flowPath::flowPath()'
testt.cpp:20:28: note: candidates are:
testt.cpp:10:5: note: flowPath::flowPath(int)
testt.cpp:10:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
testt.cpp:5:8: note: flowPath::flowPath(const flowPath&)
testt.cpp:5:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include "FlowGraph.cpp"
using namespace std;

struct flowPath {
    int vertex;
    Edge *edge;
    Edge *res;

    flowPath(int v){
      vertex = v;
    }
};

void bfs(vector<flowPath>& parentPath){
   //Stuffs
}

int main(void) {
    vector<flowPath> path(5);
    bfs(path);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't get half of the error, and I've tried to google the stuff but failed... Thanks in advance!

Comment: `vector` requires a default constructor for the type (`flowpath`)

Comment: Notice the `error:` part. Location and notes come after.

Comment: I've a constructor, flowpath(int v){}?

Comment: **default** constructor

Comment: why do you add #include "FlowGraph.cpp"?, besides your constructor is defined by int and is trying to take default constructor.

Comment: @uelordi That's where Edge class thingie is defined.

Comment: ok, it sounds me weird but if it works no prob.

Comment: I'm not familiar with default constructors. Will flowpath(){} work as one?

Comment: @Sakutard depends how you define "work". After construction the object should be in a valid state, ie. you should at least set the pointers to null

Comment: That will compile. Whether it woks or not totally depends on what `flowpath` needs to initialize to function. For example, not setting `edge` and `res` to `nullptr` leaves you open to some nasty runtime bugs easily slipping through and wreaking havoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a default constructor for `flowPath` as follows (for example, can be done differently of course):

```
struct flowPath {
    int vertex;
    Edge* edge;
    Edge* res;

    flowPath() : vertex(0), edge(nullptr), res(nullptr) {}

    //...
};
```

Then you can use `flowPath` in a `std::vector`.

Alternatively, if you don't want a default constructor in `flowPath` then instead use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<flowPath>>` (you could also use `std::vector<flowPath*>` but using smart pointers is more in line with modern c++).

Comment: Will "flowpath(){}" do as default constructor?

Comment: @Sakutard Technically, yes, but that means the fields of `flowPath` will not be initialised to anything which could cause issues if you attempt to access them without setting them later on.

Comment: I've tried to make an new object of my struct "flowPath fp = new flowPath(0)" but get the error 
"invalid conversion from 'flowPath*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
initializing argument 1 of 'flowPath::flowPath(int)' [-fpermissive]". Why?

Comment: @Sakutard If you want to make an object of type `flowPath` using the `flowPath(int)` constructor then simply do `flowPath fp(0);` to call this appropriate constructor. Using `new` allocates memory on the heap and is only applicable to pointer to object types, so you would have to do `flowPath* fp = new flowPath(0);` - but that is inadvisable in modern c++ due to memory management headaches.

Comment: Sorry another related question. If I try to check whenever a element in my vector "vector<flowPath> path" is empty or not, I get lots of error messages saying that there's no match for the operator. Example: "if(path[2] == NULL)". Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Sakutard To compare something with `NULL` or `nullptr` (the latter is better) it needs to be a pointer, but you have a `std::vector<flowPath>` rather than a vector of pointers to `flowPath`. Either you need to use something like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<flowPath>>` or a different comparison operation for checking if a `flowPath` is empty - e.g: `path[2].edge == nullptr && path[2].res == nullptr`, depending upon what you require.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
vector<flowPath> path(5);
```

Doesn't pass `5` to the constructor of `flowpath`, but just to the `vector`. The value `5` here means allocate and reserve memory for 5 elements. `vector` requires the type (`flowpath` in your case) to have default constructor accessible.

You may need to have default constructor in `flowpath` class, or make the parameter default:

```
flowPath(int v = 1 ){
      vertex = v;
    }
```

Comment: Yea I get it, I just want the vector to be that big.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
struct flowPath {
    int vertex;
    Edge *edge;
    Edge *res;
    flowPath(int v){
      vertex = v;
    }
};

void bfs(vector<struct flowPath>& parentPath){
   //Stuffs
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<struct flowPath> path(1,5); /*One vector of dimension 1 will be created, and the value of 5 will be passed to the constructor*/
    //bfs(path);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!